# Using ArcObjects to allow assignment of unique numeric IDs

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

In ArcMap 10.6 > Data Frame Properties > We have the "Allow assignment of unique numeric IDs for map service publishing" and the associated Layer > Properties > General > Layer ID settings.  I have 200 layers in 10 different MXD documents; so I would love to automate this process but unable to find a suitable interface in FeatureLayer or GeoFeatureLayer Coclass.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a good trawl of the object model and find no property or method that enables that tick box. I've come to the conclusion there is no object that exposes that property, but I could be wrong?

As an idea you could step through the layers in a map and set the ID manually using [ILayerDescription3.ID](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ILayerDescription3.htm)? Not tried it personally.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I did the same!  Not sure if that is the right approach though!  ILayerDescription  is from Server Objects?  I am working on ArcMap mxd.  From Documentation : ["Use ILayerDescription to access layer settings that can be changed on the server object...."](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ILayerDescription3.htm)